# Customize face can use some theme faces, but not all

Tags: faces, themes, customize-face

[This is my theme config](https://github.com/fleutot/.emacs.d/blob/master/themes/bisque-theme.el).

I am trying to modify the face `list-matching-lines-buffer-name-face`, which is part of the result window of `occur` (see replace.el.gz).

Using `customize-option` on `list-matching-lines-buffer-name-face`, I am experimenting with what works and what doesn't.

In the customization buffer, I can use some other faces to assign to `list-matching-lines-buffer-name-face`. For example, reusing `magit-bisect-bad` works (`sample` shows that directly). Some others, which are in my theme linked above, do not work, for example `linum`.

[image]

[image]

Extract of the theme file:

```
`(linum ((t (:foreground ,bisque-green+2 :background ,bisque-bg))))
...
`(magit-bisect-bad  ((t (:foreground ,bisque-red))))
```

Why are only some of the faces available to assign to my option?

---

How do I set the value of `list-matching-lines-buffer-name-face` in my theme file? I eventually don't want to set it with customize, I want it to be only for that theme, not in my init file.

I've tried to set faces in my theme file:

```
`(occur-buffer-name-face ((t (:foreground ,bisque-bg :background ,bisque-green  :weight bold))))
`(list-matching-lines-buffer-name-face ((t (:foreground ,bisque-bg :background ,bisque-green  :weight bold))))
```

with no success. The first of these two (`occur-buffer-name-face`) I've tried to use in the customize interface, with no luck either.

---

As a summary, this is what I have:

- The result of `occur` has standard face for buffer names (it is as default, plus `underline`)
- `M-x customize-face`
- search for `list-matching-lines-buffer-name-face`
- check that the face description on the right of the sample text `sample` only says `underline`. The `sample` text shows underlined text with default foreground color.
- change `underline` to `magit-bisect-bad`. The sample text changes as soon as the face name is done (turns red in my case).
- change `magit-bisect-bad` to `linum`

Expected behavior: the sample text turns to green foreground, as set by my theme.

Actual behavior: the sample text stays as default foreground.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing, and thus why you say only some faces are available etc. Please provide a step-by-step recipe of what you are doing in each case in `M-x customize-face`. Say what you do at each step (in each case - setting the var to face `linum` and setting it to face `magit-bisect-bad`), and say what you see in each step, and  what you expected/want to see instead.

Comment: The screenshots you show indicate that you *edited* the option value, but you didn't *set* it. Did you actually set it in your testing?

Comment: As I mentioned in previous comment, you should use `setq` rather than `custom-theme-set-faces` to modified `list-matching-lines-buffer-name-face`

Comment: @Drew I am reading face names in my theme file, and trying them out in the interface of customize. When I'm done writing `magit-bisect-bad`, the sample text `sample` changes accordingly. No need to apply, set, it changes as soon as the face name is there. This is not the case with `linum`, it does not change.

Comment: Put all such info in your question, as part of the recipe/description. Questions need to stand on their own. Comments are not searchable, and they can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: @Drew I thought I didi: "For example, reusing `magit-bisect-bad` works (`sample` shows that directly)", but I understand that this gets buried in the rest of the question. Will try to make it clearer.

Comment: @TianshuWang Thank you. I got it to work with first going a `defface` for a new face, then assigning it to `list-matching-lines-buffer-name-face`. What confuses me is that `list-macthing-lines-buffer-name-face` shows up in `customize`, it surprises me if it's just a variable and not a face.

Comment: @Gauthier You can also customize a variable via `customize-variable`.

Answer (score 0):

My current way to solve this is this, in my theme file:

```
;; In the big `let` statement of my theme.
(defface occur-buffer-name '((t (:background "#5c888b" :foreground "#45423f")))
  "Occur buffer name lineface"
  :group 'basic-faces)
(setq list-matching-lines-buffer-name-face 'occur-buffer-name)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find the correct way *not* to use hard-coded values there. Since my theme defines a palette, I would like to use the palette colors.

Thanks @TianshuWang for guiding me to using `setq`.

(but I still don't understand why this face cannot be set like the other faces, in [my theme](https://github.com/fleutot/.emacs.d/blob/master/themes/bisque-theme.el)'s `custom-theme-set-faces`.)

---

As reference, this is how my colors are defined in my theme file:

```
(deftheme bisque "The bisque color theme, based on zenburn")

;; Palette
(let ((class '((class color) (min-colors 89)))
      ;; Zenburn palette
      ;; colors with +x are lighter, colors with -x are darker
      ;; #ac9a85 = (bisque3 + bisque4) / 2
      (bisque-fg "#ac9a85")
      (bisque-fg-1 "bisque4")
      (bisque-fg-2 "#5f5549")
;; ...
```

then comes the definition of the faces, within the same `let`:

```
  (custom-theme-set-faces
   'bisque
   '(button ((t (:underline t))))
   `(link ((t (:foreground ,bisque-yellow :underline t :weight bold))))
   `(link-visited ((t (:foreground ,bisque-yellow-2 :underline t :weight normal))))

   ;;; basic coloring
   `(default ((t (:foreground ,bisque-fg :background ,bisque-bg))))
   `(cursor ((t (:foreground ,bisque-fg :background ,bisque-yellow+1))))
   `(escape-glyph ((t (:foreground ,bisque-yellow :bold t))))
   `(fringe ((t (:foreground ,bisque-yellow+1 :background ,bisque-bg))))
   `(header-line ((t (:foreground ,bisque-yellow
                                  :background ,bisque-bg-1))))
                                  ;;:box (:line-width -1 :style released-button)))))
   `(highlight ((t (:background ,bisque-bg-05))))

   ;;; compilation
   `(compilation-column-face ((t (:foreground ,bisque-yellow))))
   `(compilation-enter-directory-face ((t (:foreground ,bisque-green))))
;; ...
```